# In Prolog, how do you use member predicate to determine the best combination?

Tags: prolog

I am very new to Prolog and find it exceptionally confusing having spent most of my time with Java and C++. I am tasked with finding different combinations of fast food given the type, calories, and price:

```
burger 450 $5 
fries 250 $2 
shake 500 $3 
salad 150 $7
```

I need to define a rule:

```
findfood(Calories, Price, Burger, Fries, Shake, Salad).
```

where burger, fries, shake, and salad can be 0 or 1 depending on whether or not they are purchased. I then need to define a rule so that you can find the most expensive combinations (yes, expensive. Apparently I enjoy spending a lot of money on food) without exceeding a certain caloric amount.

I'm very confused on how the member/rules come in to play here. I found a few examples on the internet, but they don't seem to apply since the foods have their own values, not just whether or not they are purchased.

I don't wish someone to write my program for me, but could anyone perhaps point me in the write direction? I don't even know where to start and that's very frustrating...

-Edit-

Using the comments below, I was able work through the first part, findfood, and figured out how to set up members to handle which items are being purchased and calculate the calories and price. Now I need to find the most expensive food combination less than or equal to a certain caloric amount. I am allowed to create multiple rules to do this. It should be something like:

```
|?- most_expensive(1000, Price, Burger, Fries, Shake, Salad)
```

and it will return the most expensive combination of food for 1000 calories. I know I'll need to do some sort of recursive comparison, but I'm not sure how to proceed. For the record, I understand recursion pretty well, just not Prolog. Can anyone perhaps explain where to go from here?

Comment: Why are you already fixated on the `member` predicate? Is it dictated by an assignment, or are you just assuming you'll use it? I would start with writing out your rules, as logically and precisely as possible, in natural language (e.g., English) and then try to express those in Prolog. Are the `0` and `1` values inputs, outputs, or possibly either? Since you're maximizing, you would want to iterate over combinations of "allowed" foods and track their total cost and/or calories. Also decide how you want to represent a food in Prolog, *e.g.*, `food(burger, 450, 5).` might be convenient.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me how you want your `findfood` rule to work, but I would also recommend rather than explicitly listing each food type as a parameter to `findfood`, pass a single list parameter including the foods you want: `findfood(Calories, Cost, FoodList)` where a `FoodList` example might be, `[burger, fries, shake]`. If you're using SWI Prolog, it has some nice built-in predicates that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm assuming member predicate because there was a comment about members in the dictation of the assignment and the quiz this week dealt with members (and this is the 2nd and final Prolog program). Obviously, we have not had much time to cover the material... 0 and 1 can be inputs or outputs. I'll see if I can implement your suggestions... Thanks again.

Comment: That's cool. `member` may come up in the implementation, depending upon how you implement. But it isn't obvious to me that it would be required or even part of a preferred approach.

Comment: After rereading the specs, yes I need to use member. I was able to implement it using a "change for a dollar" example I found online and calculate the weight and value using the same example. As per the specs, I need to pass parameters individually instead of in a list. Now I'm stuck on the second part...